# Given the following Riccati equation and the 4 solutions $y_{1}$ , $y_{2}$ , $y_{3}$ , $y_{4}$ . prove that the following expression is constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Riccati equation:
$$y'(x)=c(x)+b(x)\,y(x)+a(x)\,y^{2}(x)$$
with the solutions:
$y_{1}$ , $y_{2}$ , $y_{3}$ , $y_{4}$
Prove that $q$ is constant:
$$ q=\frac{\ (y_{3} -y_{1})(y_{4} - y_{2})}{(y_{3}-y_{2})(y_{4}-y_{1})}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $y_1, y_2, y_3$  and $y_4$ are four solutions of given Riccati equation, then we can have following set of equations [Dropping the argument $x$ for convenience].

$y_1'=ay_1^2+b y_1 + c$

$y_2'=ay_2^2+b y_2 + c$

$y_3'=ay_3^2+b y_3 + c$

$y_4'=ay_4^2+b y_4 + c$

Now, **Eq.$(3)$ - Eq.$(1):$**

$ \frac{d}{dx} (y_3-y_1)= a(y_3^2-y_1^2) + b(y_3 -y_1) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx} \ln(y_3-y_1)=a(y_3+y_1) + b$

Similarly, **Eq.$(4)$ - Eq.$(2):$**

$ \frac{d}{dx} (y_4-y_2)= a(y_4^2-y_2^2) + b(y_4 -y_2) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx} \ln(y_4-y_2)=a(y_4+y_2) + b$

Now, **adding last two equations:**

$  \frac{d}{dx} \ln[(y_3-y_1)(y_4-y_2)]= a(y_3+y_1)+a(y_4+y_2) + 2b$

Similar to the last equation,we can also write,

$  \frac{d}{dx} \ln[(y_3-y_2)(y_4-y_1)]= a(y_3+y_2)+a(y_4+y_1) + 2b$

Again, subtracting the last two equations:

$  \frac{d}{dx} \ln[\frac{(y_3-y_1)(y_4-y_2)}{(y_3-y_2)(y_4-y_1)}] = 0$

$\frac{(y_3-y_1)(y_4-y_2)}{(y_3-y_2)(y_4-y_1)}=\exp[C]=q.$

**Hence $q$ is a constant.**